# cin array, while loop 2 times

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

```
int a[20], b[20];

int input;

int asize = 0;

cout << "Please enter array A: ";
while (cin >> input)
{
    a[asize] = input;

    ++asize;
}

int input2;
int bsize = 0;

cout << "Please enter array B: ";
while (cin >> input2)
{
    b[bsize] = input2;

    ++bsize;
}
```

Example:
I wanted user to input = 1 2 3 q for a
input = 2 3 4 6 7 q for b
so the array for a will be 1 2 3 and b will be 2 3 4 6 7
but the loop just stopped at the first while loop, i dont know why, can any one make suggestion?

Comment: `cin >> input` will only write input that can be converted to an `int` into `input`. entering `'q'` makes the input fail ad places the stream into a fail state until the serror is acknowledged by `clear`ing the failure flag (and usually followed up by removing the bad input so the next read won't trip over it and fail  again). The flag was not cleared so `cin >> input2` instantly fails.

Comment: Typical solutions are to read into a `std::string`, test for the terminating message, and if the input isn't the terminator, attempt to convert the `string` into an `int` and store it.

Comment: Having trouble finding a good, solid duplicate, but someone will.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't forget to build in tests like `if (asize < 20)` to prevent the user putting in so many numbers that they overrun the array.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for your informed information! i understand the problem more clearly. Is there a way to clear that flag?

Comment: I was a bit too obtuse. Sorry about that. [`cin.clear();`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) clears (and sets, weirdly enough) the flags.

Comment: thank you! it is solved! i added cin.clear(); also cin.ignore(); it doesnt work with only one, only works with both

Comment: `ignore` is often an easy way to remove bad input from a stream, but what if the bad input is not a `'q'`? Suggestion: Read into and `int` the way you currently are. When the read fails, `clear` the flags, then read into a `char`. Test the `char` to see if it is a `'q'`. If it is, proceed to the next loop. If it is not, notify the user that they screwed up and throw out the rest of the user's input with `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`. You'll need to include the `<limits>` header.

Comment: Appreciate your knowledge sharing! i will look into it more, thank you so much!